# How to tell a disk failure in RAID1

Tags: dell, hard-drive, raid1

I have an old Dell poweredge R200 in collocation which has 2 hard disks in RAID 1. I am wondering how should I know if one one the disks is failed?

Comment: The controller software will tell you. What OS are you running?

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu 10.10 (64 bit) but I have no idea what the controller sofware is, as the OS is installed by the colo hosting

Comment: you should go through some of your old questions and mark the most useful answers as accepted. 17% is kind of a discouraging number to see when people are considering helping you :) (Sorry I don't happen to know about your problem but I thought I'd suggest this because it helps you to be part of the community here)

Comment: Ok Caleb, I'll try to ask easier questions, so that people can give acceptable answers and I can improve my rates :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you install Dell Open Manage (can be downloaded from their web site) you will be able to see the state of the disks and many, many other things as well

Comment: How should I install the DOM software, regarding that my server is in colo, and I have no direct access to it?

Comment: Dell OpenManage should run OK in Ubuntu. If the server is in colo and you have no access to it, then you need to get the hosting company to insert the CD for you and install it.

Comment: Thanks wolfgangsZ and Phil. I am going to ask them to install Dell OpenManage